# Setting up Magento Cron for selected indexing

Tags: magento-1.8, cron

Magento 1.8

How can I setup a cron job for Indexing particularly Product Prices?

This is my current cron script but it doesn't seem to run

```
4 * * * * php -f /shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script location is very likely to be wrong.  The preceding slash indicates that the script exists at server root (not webserver root) under the shell directory.  I'm guessing you are wanting instead to execute the script within the Magento install.

You need to determine the user the cron job is running under and firstly ensure that user has sufficient permissions to run the script.  Once you have done that either use an absolute path to the script as you are now, but from server root instead of webserver root, or enter the location relative to the users home directory (which will be the starting location cron executes from).

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, my server root is var/www/. However when i input the code as such >`php -f var/www/shell/indexer.php reindexall` 
Could not open input file: var/www/shell/indexer.php

Comment: Thats a relative path as you have no preceding slash, is `var/www/shell/indexer.php` relative to the cron users home directory?  If it's an absolute server path you need `/var/www/shell/indexer.php` instead.